# How can I sort mongodb results using LINQ against MongoCollection<T>.AsQueryable()?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB to store entities that can contain a variable number of user-defined index values. Each index can contain one or more values, so for the user-defined indices, I use a dictionary of object lists to store the values.

```
public class Entity
{
    public IDictionary<string, IList<object>> Indices { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

I wrote a repository class that supports querying the entities by passing a list of custom criteria, and the repository builds an instance of `IMongoQuery` using the `MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query` class, and returns an `IQueryable<Entity>`

```
public IQueryable<Entity> GetAll(IEnumerable<SearchCriterion> criteria)
{
    IMongoQuery query = BuildQuery(criteria);

    //https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-461
    //return _db.GetCollection<Entity>().Find(query).AsQueryable();

    return _db.GetCollection<Entity>()
        .AsQueryable()
        .Where(x => query.Inject());
}
```

Due to the issue described here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-461 I chose not to use the `MongoCursor.AsQueryable()` because MongoCursor implements IEnumerable. As a result. any expressions used on the returned `IQueryable<Entity>` is not done on the server, it is done in memory on the client side. Instead, I inject my query into the `MongoCollection<T>.AsQueryable()` results as suggested.

So, the solution above works great, but now I would like to sort the results by doing the same thing with a call to `OrderBy()` using the `IMongoSortBy` interface, like so.

```
return _db.GetCollection<Entity>()
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => query.Inject())
    .OrderBy(x => sortBy.Inject());
```

However, there is no implementation of Inject() on the IMongoSortBy interface

If I were using the MongoCursor, this would be easy

```
return _db.GetCollection<Entity>()
    .Find(query).
    .SetSortOrder(sortBy)
    .AsQueryable();
```

So, is there a way I can perform a sort on the entities using the call to `MongoCollection<T>.AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Why can't you use a simple linq OrderBy?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. Not every document has the key that is being searched. Performing an OrderBy(x => x.Indices["index name"][0]) can result in a key not found error.

Comment: And i guess you're insisting on IQueryable so you can add filters after both the query and the sort right?

Comment: Nice question, but i don't think that's possible. Good luck though...

Comment: Thanks, I may just have to rethink my approach and implement all my filters through the criteria API rather than linq and return an IEnumerable. I was hoping to avoid this, but it may be my only option.